# Почему выводит только последнюю строку из бд?

Tags: php

Почему выводит только последнюю строку из бд?

```
include "acc/bd.php";

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");

while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = '"'.$myrow['login'].'",';

}
$name = substr($name, 0, -1);
$name = "[".$name."]";
echo $name;
```

Должно быть так: вывело все имена в лапках через запятую, потом убрало одну запятую в конце, а потом запихнуть это все в квадратные скобки.

Comment: до цикла объявите переменную `$name = ''` а в цикле конкатинируйте к ней `$name .= `

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так точно выведет все, если кодировка utf-8:

```
include "acc/bd.php";

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
$names = [];    
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $names[] = $myrow['login']; 
}
echo json_encode($names);
```

Вы в цикле каждый раз сбрасываете значение $name - первая ошибка. Вторая ошибка - вы похоже пытаетесь получить JSON в ответе, но не учитываете, что в именах может быть теоретически кавычка, или символ - не поддерживаемый стандартом JSON.